# Mail Bounce due to Invalid string MX record

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

I'm new to managing a mail server and I encounter an issue with sending a message to a certain domain.

Our emails are bouncing back on us with the error of the Invalid MX record string.

I'm using Lotus Domino.

Below the message I got on bounce email:

[<00>] XMail bounce: Rcpt=[makibaoh@smart.com.ph];Error=[Invalid MX records string format]

[<01>] Error sending message [1620000931566.5a6ffb70.1089.1bb0f.protect] from [protect.cardmri.com].

ID:        <21050300-6320-0000-0000-000002A2C8E0>
Mail From: pingu@cardmri.com
Rcpt To:   makibaoh@smart.com.ph
Server:    [smart.com.ph]

**[<02>] The reason of the delivery failure was:
Invalid MX records string format**

Comment: Hi, does sending a email there work from a public email (ie; hotmail, gmail, etc..) ? Does in mxtoolbox website the remote mx seem ok ?

Comment: I've edited it now with the real domain. My main concern was the Invalid MX records string format, which we thought the root cause of mail bounce back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination domain has a malformed MX record.

```
$ dig mx smart.com.ph

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.4 <<>> mx smart.com.ph
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4883
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;smart.com.ph.                  IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
smart.com.ph.           796     IN      MX      20 mx2.hc370-38.ap.iphmx.com\032.
smart.com.ph.           796     IN      MX      10 mx1.hc370-38.ap.iphmx.com.
```

That `\032` should not be there.

There's nothing you, as a sender, can do to fix this; the recipient needs to correct their DNS record.